# Cannot obtain value from PHP form on clicking "submit"

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to PHP, and attempting to create a simple form using HTML and PHP. I'm using Apache Netbeans with XAMPP to run the PHP file on Google Chrome. Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>An example website</h1>
        <p>This is an example website to test HTML & PHP</p>
        <form action="myform.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>a
        <?php
        if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
            echo $_POST['name'];
        }                 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I've created a form on the HTML page, and I'm trying to print the value that I've typed in on clicking the Submit button. I'm sure I'm missing something basic here, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. Here's what happens when I load the page and type my name into the form field:

[image]

Here is the error in the above image in text:

> Notice: Undefined index: formSubmit in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestPHP\index.php on line 20

Then when I click the "Submit" button, this happens:

[image]

Here is the error in the above image in text:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.6

Can anyone clarify what is actually happening here, and what I would need to do in order to grab the value entered in the form field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few different issues here...

Firstly, on the "notice" you get for the variable not being set - this is because you're trying to check the value of the POST variable before anything has been posted to the page.

You can overcome this by checking if the value is set first like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
```

You get the error message above because E_NOTICE is enabled - see [Error Reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for more from the PHP docs

Secondly, your form is pointing to a page that doesn't exist. It seems your form and the part which checks the post value is on `index.php` but your form is pointing to `myform.php`.

You need to update your `<form` to point to `index.php` instead

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

To put it all together:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>An example website</h1>
        <p>This is an example website to test HTML & PHP</p>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>a
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
            echo $_POST['name'];
        }                 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So your answer combined with @RiggsFolly's both helped me to solve the problem, and I would happily accept both. I'm accepting yours because of the detailed explanation which has helped me to understand why my code was going wrong. Thanks both for the lightning quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

First time the script run, the form has not been submitted. So there are various ways of checking that the PHP script is running as a result of a submit, this is one

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") {
```

The second error may be caused because you are trying to run another script by using a `action="myform.php"`

Is the script you show us called `myform.php` if not then you can leave tha t param blank like this

```
action=""
```

and it will cause this script to be run to process the form data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to submit data on same page you can use

```
    <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have set your form action to myform.php but there exist no myform.php page

set your form action to blank if you want to print the name on the same page

and replace your php code with this

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) {
            echo $_POST['name'];
        }                 
?>
```